# How can I get files at py-vt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, antivirus

I'm trying to get files to scan it at py-vt. But every times I try to run it, it giving that error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    file=client.get_object("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/PyPhisher-main/PyPhisher-main/pyphisher.py")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt\venv\Lib\site-packages\vt\client.py", line 534, in get_object
    return make_sync(self.get_object_async(path, *path_args, params=params))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt\venv\Lib\site-packages\vt\utils.py", line 27, in make_sync
    return event_loop.run_until_complete(future)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt\venv\Lib\site-packages\vt\client.py", line 539, in get_object_async
    return await self._response_to_object(response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt\venv\Lib\site-packages\vt\client.py", line 274, in _response_to_object
    json_response = await self._response_to_json(response)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\vt\venv\Lib\site-packages\vt\client.py", line 270, in _response_to_json
    raise error
vt.error.APIError: ('ClientError', '<html>\n <head>\n  <title>404 Not Found</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <h1>404 Not Found</h1>\n  The resource could not be found.<br /><br />\n\n\n\n </body>\n</html>')
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001716E81EF90>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x000001716E7EB310>, 184240.546)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x000001716E81ED50>
```

And there's my code to run:

```
import vt
client= vt.Client("mytoken")
file=client.get_object("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/PyPhisher-main/PyPhisher-main/pyphisher.py")
```

I've tried describing path with files extension and define it with '/'.

Comment: Did you mean to use [scan_file](https://virustotal.github.io/vt-py/api/client.html#vt.Client.scan_file) (see https://virustotal.github.io/vt-py/quickstart.html#scan-a-file)?

Comment: Yes, im trying to scan files

Comment: And does it help to use `scan_file` instead of `get_object`?

Comment: No, first i've tried to handle files with get_object but at both of them im getting same error